# Magento 2 :Admin Configuration

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, system-config

I want to add some implementaion code in system configuration section for my custom module. How is that possible. Please help.

This is my block file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Implementationcode extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_directoryHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = parent::_getElementHtml($element);
        $html .= "<div>Code for Implementing Responsive Banner Slider</div>";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

This is my `system.xml` file

```
 <group id="slider" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Implementaion Code</label>
                <field id="slider" translate="label" type="hidden" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">                   
                    <source_model>Vendor\Respbannerslider\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Implementationcode</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
```

Comment: you want to add your own field in configuration and then need to use that data in your block ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work because you specified a source model.

As a reminder:

- Source models: a model class that serves to get existing values (stored in the db or somewhere else) for further displaying inside the setting’s field. Example: the yes/no source model.
- Frontend models : as a rule, it’s a block’s class. Methods of this class return html of setting’s field. To be more specific, the block had to have method `_getElementHtml()` described inside the class which returns the raw html of setting’s field
- Backend models : a class which allows to operate with configuration data on the different stages (save, load). It contains three major methods respectively for each event: `_afterLoad()`, `_beforeSave()` and `_afterSave()`.

In your case, you need to use a frontend model:

```
<group id="slider" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Implementaion Code</label>
    <field id="slider" translate="label" type="hidden" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">                   
        <frontend_model>Cartin24\Respbannerslider\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Implementationcode</frontend_model>
    </field>
</group>
```